# Emberjs - Reload the model too many time

Tags: ember.js

In my web app, I have created a button that allow the user to refresh the model. Basically, once you press this button, it trigger a function in my controller that `getJSON` the data from the server and just update like that `this.set('model', newModel');`.

It seems that most of the time when I "spam" click on this button (you have to wait to the previous download is done to be able to click again), ember give me an error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined 
Ember.CollectionView.Ember.ContainerView.extend.arrayWillChange 
(anonymous function) 
l 
l 
e 
i 
Ember.trySet 
a._sync 
r.flush 
n.end 
(anonymous function)
```

Is it possible that ember doesn't support to be spam with new model to set ? or it's something else ?

Comment: Sounds like a race condition, can you reproduce in Ember.jsbin.com, looks like fun to track down?  Or possibly some other issue with your code, is it really as simplistic as your code only does `this.set('model', newModel)` or are there observers/other things that asynchronous are watching that model

Comment: It is really as simplistic a `this.set('model', newModel);` I manipulate the model only with this code. I will try to create a jsBin .